# Combine columns from different tables (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to combine 3 tables into one. I'm using SQL Server 2005. I tried `FULL OUTER JOIN` but got duplicate IDs in the results. So your help is much appreciated.

```
+---------------+   +---------------+    +---------------+ 
| ID   COL_A    |   | ID    COL_B   |    | ID    COL_C   |
+---------------+   +---------------+    +---------------+
| a    2        |   | b     1       |    | a     1       |
| c    1        |   | c     1       |    | d     1       |
+---------------+   +---------------+    +---------------+
```

Results:

```
+---------------------------+
| ID   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C  |
+---------------------------+   
| a    2      NULL   1      | 
| b    NULL   1      NULL   |
| c    1      1      NULL   |
| d    NULL   NULL   1      |
+---------------------------+
```

each table has different rows of data.

here's the code that creates the tables:

```
declare @a table (
    ID      char(1),
    COL_A   int
)
declare @b table (
    ID      char(1),
    COL_B   int
)
declare @c table (
    ID      char(1),
    COL_C   int
)

insert into @a values ('a', 2)
insert into @a values ('c', 1)

insert into @b values ('b', 1)
insert into @b values ('c', 1)

insert into @c values ('a', 1)
insert into @c values ('d', 1)

select * from @a
select * from @b
select * from @c
```

Thank you!

---

**@Francis Fuerte**, my full-join query looks like this:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(c.ID,a.ID,b.ID) AS ID
       ,a.COL_A
       ,b.COL_B
       ,c.COL_C 
FROM @c c 
FULL OUTER JOIN @a a ON c.ID=a.ID
FULL OUTER JOIN @b b ON c.ID=b.ID  
ORDER BY ID
```

**@Nithesh**, if the order of the tables being joined changes, the result changes too.

```
SELECT  ISNULL(ISNULL(a.ID,b.ID),c.ID) AS ID
       ,a.COL_A
       ,b.COL_B
       ,c.COL_C 
FROM @a a 
FULL OUTER JOIN @b b ON a.ID=b.ID  
FULL OUTER JOIN @c c ON a.ID=c.ID
ORDER BY ID

SELECT  ISNULL(ISNULL(b.ID,a.ID),c.ID) AS ID
       ,a.COL_A
       ,b.COL_B
       ,c.COL_C 
FROM @b b 
FULL OUTER JOIN @a a ON b.ID=a.ID  
FULL OUTER JOIN @c c ON b.ID=c.ID
ORDER BY ID

SELECT  ISNULL(ISNULL(c.ID,b.ID),a.ID) AS ID
       ,a.COL_A
       ,b.COL_B
       ,c.COL_C 
FROM @c c 
FULL OUTER JOIN @b b ON c.ID=b.ID  
FULL OUTER JOIN @a a ON c.ID=a.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

results: (sorry, don't have enough reputation to post images)

```
+---------------------------+
| ID   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C  |
+---------------------------+   
| a    2      NULL   1      | 
| b    NULL   1      NULL   |
| c    1      1      NULL   |
| d    NULL   NULL   1      |
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
| ID   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C  |
+---------------------------+   
| a    2      NULL   NULL   | 
| a    NULL   NULL   1      |
| b    NULL   1      NULL   |
| c    1      1      NULL   |
| d    NULL   NULL   1      |
+---------------------------+
+---------------------------+
| ID   COL_A  COL_B  COL_C  |
+---------------------------+   
| a    2      NULL   1      | 
| b    NULL   1      NULL   |
| c    NULL   1      NULL   |
| c    1      NULL   NULL   |
| d    NULL   NULL   1      |
+---------------------------+
```

Do I really need to add an extra layer with GROUPBY clause to avoid duplicates?

Comment: can you show your full outer join query?

Comment: @Francis Fuerte, sure, I added my query to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample there, the following will work:

```
SELECT ISNULL(AB.ID, C.ID) AS [ID], AB.COL_A, AB.COL_B, C.COL_C
FROM (
    SELECT ISNULL(A.ID, B.ID) AS [ID], A.COL_A, B.COL_B
    FROM @a A
    FULL OUTER JOIN @b B
        ON A.ID = B.ID
) AB
FULL OUTER JOIN @c C
    ON AB.ID = C.ID
ORDER BY ISNULL(AB.ID, C.ID)
```

Basically, do a FULL OUTER JOIN of A+B, then use the result of that to join to C.

Comment: looks like this is more error-proof. The only concern I have is about the performance. The prototype I gave above only involves 3 tables. In reality, there are more tables to join so the nesting will get deeper.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id, max(Col_A) as Col_A, max(Col_B) as Col_B, max(Col_C) as Col_c
from ((select id, col_A, NULL as col_B, NULL as COL_C
       from @a
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL, col_B, NULL
       from @b
      ) union all
      (select id, NULL, NULL, COL_C
       from @c
      )
     ) abc
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article on join types that would be beneficial to read through.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/

Assuming you want to keep the identity of where the data came from.  Col A, Col B, Col C

Not sure what you are expecting in your return, but from what I can see you should change to an inner join between your tables.  Just remember you can only join one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  case when a.ID IS not null then a.ID 
        when b.ID IS not null then b.ID 
        when c.ID IS not null then c.ID 
    end id
    ,a.COL_A
    ,b.COL_B 
    ,c.COL_C
from    @a a full outer join @b b on a.ID = b.id
         full outer join @c c on a.ID = c.id
order by 1
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  ISNULL(ISNULL(a.ID,b.ID),c.ID) AS ID
       ,a.COL_A
       ,b.COL_B
       ,c.COL_C 
FROM @a a 
FULL OUTER JOIN @b b ON a.ID=b.ID  
FULL OUTER JOIN @c c ON a.ID=c.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: if the order of tables being joined changes, the result changes:

Comment: how? can you please explain?

Comment: Sure, I have put the code snippet and results in the context of my original question.

Comment: the order defined by you? then why you going for rea-arranging. also a sub-query which you chosen as answer now wont give you a better performance. Actually what leads you to change the order of join?

Comment: I understand that sub-query may cause performance issues. I chose it as the answer for it gives consistent results regardless of the order of joins. There can be more than 3 tables and they are not necessarily joined by a specific order. So I'm trying to figure out why the order matters in the case. If the order eventually affects the results, I'm afraid I can't take it as the solution. Have to go for the sub-query instead.

Comment: The issue with your join is that if B & C have a row for an ID but A doesn't, you'll get two rows with that ID (since there's no join on B->C or a coalesce on A->B, to see the issue add `insert into @b values ('d', 1)` to your inserts. Note that this can be fixed by adding `OR b.ID=c.ID` to your 2nd join.

Comment: @Timothy Walters, thank you for sharing the insights and solving the puzzle!